# Indefinite thread waiting in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, wait, notify

I am trying to generate Odd/Even numbers using 2 threads using wait notify.

But It is just printing **1**.

Below is the code:

**Even.java**

```
public class Even implements Runnable {
    private int i; private Object ob
    public Even(int i,Object o) {
    this.i=i;
    this.ob=o;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (ob) {
                while (i % 2 == 0) {
                    try {
                        ob.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                i++;
                System.out.println(i);
                ob.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Odd.java**

```
public class Odd implements Runnable {
    private int i; private Object ob;
    public Odd(int i) {
        this.i=i;
        this.ob=o;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (ob) {
                while (i % 2 == 1) {
                    try {
                        ob.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                i++;
                System.out.println(i);
                ob.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        Object lock = new Object();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Even(i),lock);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Odd(i),lock);
        t1.start();
        t2.start(); 
    }       
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
```

Can anyone tell me where I am making the mistake?

Comment: Your `Odd` constructor is missing the `o` parameter. And you're passing `lock` to your thread constructors instead of to your runnables. Maybe post something that compiles.

Comment: Your inner `while` loops don't make sense and are going to spin indefinitely because `i` is not shared between threads.

Comment: If you tried debugging your code, you would see clearly what's going on and why.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I would assume that it could be a problem that Integer appears to be immutable in Java. Thus you will not synchronize on the same objects anymore, if one of the two classes changed the i value (which it apparently does since the first output is 1).

So since you change the value stored in `i` in `Odd` and call `notifyAll` on the new object I that Java will complain since you call `notifyAll` on an object that actually never has been locked.

Comment: I am using a fixed Object in locking

Comment: Ok you updated your code. Fine.
Now you have the issue that both while loops create deadlocks. The first one say `while(i % 2 == 0) { ...}  i++;`. But note that at the beginning `i=0` and thus this object will never escape from the `while`-loop.

In `Odd` `while(i % 2 == 1) { ...}  i++;` it will go beyond the `while`-loop once, print one and then get caught as well.

Comment: where I need to make the change?

Comment: At the moment I would just say you could remove all that synchronised stuff since you do not have a global variable shared between both threads that you would change. So the `run` method of `Odd` could look as follows:

`public void run() { while(true) { i++;if (i % 2 == 1) {System.out.println(i); }}}}` 

(Sorry for the ugly code formatting :( )

Answer (score 1):

The threads have fallen into ***INDEFINITE WAITING*** state. Note that (`t1` i.e instance of `Even` and `t2` i.e instance of `Odd`), each have a separate copy of instance variable `i`.

**Here is whats going on behind the scenes:**

- Initially, both thread `t1` (`Even`) and `t2` (`Odd`) are in **READY** and then **RUNNABLE** state
- Lets assume `t1` is scheduled and gets processor to execute. `t1` enters **RUNNING** state. `t1`'s `run()` is invoked

  - `while(true)` succeeds and control enters outer while loop
  - because of `synchronized(ob)` `t1` locks object `ob`
  - since `i` is `0` initially; `i % 2 == 0` condition evaluates to `true`
  - control now enters body of inner while loop, then `try` block and invokes `ob.wait();`
  - `t1` enters **WAITING** state and waits until someone notifies on object `ob`
- Now, `t2` is scheduled and gets processor to execute. `t2` enters **RUNNING** state

  - `while(true)` succeeds and control enters outer while loop
  - because of `synchronized(ob)` `t2` locks object `ob`
  - `i` is `0` initially (remember the `i` incremented previously was local to `t1` - `Even`.`i`). The variable `i` in this context is local to `t2` i.e. `Odd`.`i`.
  - Hence `i % 2 == 1` evaluates to `false` and control skips inner while loop
  - Control reaches `i++;` `i` is incremented from `0` to `1`
  - The statement `System.out.println(i);` prints `1` to console
  - contorl moves to next line and `ob.notifyAll();` is invoked and all the threads waiting on object `ob` (`t1` in our case) are notified
- At this point, both `t1` and `t2` are back in **RUNNABLE** state again
- Depends on processor which thread to schedule
- Lets assume `t1` is scheduled and gets processor to execute

  - `t1` resumes its operations from where it left previously (i.e the statement after `ob.wait();`)
  - control reaches `catch (InterruptedException e)` and since there is no exception, its skipped and control comes back to `while ( i % 2 == 0)` check
  - Remember, `t1`'s `i` (i.e `Even`.`i`) is still `0` because control din't reach the line `i++;` in `Even` class
  - Hence `i % 2 == 0` evaluates to `true` and control enters into body of while loop, then enters the try block and invokes `ob.wait();`
  - `t1` enters **WAITING** state again and waits until someone notifies on object ob
- Now, `t2` is scheduled and gets processor to execute. `t2` enters **RUNNING** state

  - `t2` resumes its operations from where it left previously (i.e the statement after `ob.notifyAll();`)
  - since there is no other statement after `ob.notifyAll();`, the control reaches outer while loop
  - `while(true)` is evaluated and control enters body of outer while loop
  - because of `synchronized(ob)` `t1` locks object `ob`
  - Remember `t2`'s `i` is now `1` because it was incremented previously and printed on console
  - Hence, `while ( i % 2 == 1)` is evaluated to `true` and control enters body of inner while loop, then `try` block and invokes `ob.wait();`
  - As a result, `t2` enters **WAITING** state
- `t1` and `t2` are both in **WAITING** state now; waiting on object `ob`. Waiting for someone to notify them on object `ob`. Sadly, there is no one to rescue

Hence the ***INDEFINITE WAITING***

Following code should help in what you are trying to achieve

```
public class EvenOddTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lock lock = new Lock();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Even(lock));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Odd(lock));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

}

class Lock {
    private int data;

    public void increment() {
        data++;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }
}

class Even implements Runnable {
    private Lock ob;

    public Even(Lock o) {
        this.ob = o;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (ob) {
                while (ob.getData() % 2 == 0) {
                    try {
                        ob.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                ob.increment();
                System.out.println(ob.getData());
                ob.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Odd implements Runnable {
    private Lock ob;

    public Odd(Lock o) {
        this.ob = o;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (ob) {
                while (ob.getData() % 2 == 1) {
                    try {
                        ob.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                ob.increment();
                System.out.println(ob.getData());
                ob.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

1. I have refactored your code so that the object on which threads try to obtain lock and wait upon, holds the data as well.
2. `lock` object is now the shared instance between `Even` and `Odd` threads.
3. With my previous reasoning, the code should be self explanatory.
4. This is not actual way of doing things in parallel computing, to leverage multi-threading power/capabilities. However, it should be a good starter exercise.

Comment: The above works and I understand my int variable was not shared between 2 threads. Is there any no way we can do above task without creating an extra class and just using either Integer/int?

Answer (score 0):

You can put i variable as a class attribute in Test class, then create an object of type Test and pass it as parameter to the constructors:

```
public class Test {

public Integer i = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object o = new Object();
    Test t = new Test();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Even(t,o));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Odd(t,o));
    t1.start();
    t2.start(); 
}
```

}

```
public class Even implements Runnable {
private Test t;
private Object o;
public Even(Test t, Object o) {
this.t=t;
this.o=o;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        synchronized (o) {
            while (t.i % 2 == 0) {
                try {
                    o.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            t.i++;
            System.out.println(t.i);
            o.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Odd implements Runnable {
private Test t;
private Object o;
public Odd(Test t, Object o) {
    this.t=t;
    this.o = o;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        synchronized (o) {
            while (t.i % 2 == 1) {
                try {
                    o.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            t.i++;
            System.out.println(t.i);
            o.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Well actually the solution appears to be quite viable. However, I would refrain from using public variables and use getters and setters instead (principle of encapsulation).

On the other hand I think one should rethink the whole approach. I mean why do you use threading? Typically to improve your speed. And if it is about such things as creating even and odd numbers I do not see a real efficiency gain in doing that via a synchronized integer variable. 

I guess I understand the learning background of the task, but keeping these things in mind is useful as well I think.